# Decryption issue when running presto queries in EMR for data encrypted using AWS client side master key

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, hive, emr, presto

I have used your latest script that successfully installs presto server(version 0.99) and java 8 on Amazon EMR instance. My data files are located in a s3 bucket encrypted with client-side customer managed key that were encrypted . When I create a hive table that references those encrypted data files in s3, hive can successfully decrypt the records and display it in console. However, when viewing the same external table from presto command line interface the data is displayed in its encrypted form. I have looked at your link given in:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.57.html 
 and added those properties in my hive.properties file and it looks like given below.

```
hive.s3.connect-timeout=2m
hive.s3.max-backoff-time=10m
hive.s3.max-error-retries=50
hive.metastore-refresh-interval=1m
hive.s3.max-connections=500
hive.s3.max-client-retries=50
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.s3.socket-timeout=2m
hive.s3.aws-access-key=***
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=**
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=20m
hive.s3.staging-directory=/mnt/tmp/
hive.s3.use-instance-credentials=true
```

Any help on how to decrypt the files in using presto cli will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We will follow-up in the issue you filed:  https://github.com/facebook/presto/issues/2945